# Real-world example of using display to change HTML elements from inline to block

Tags: html, css, display, inline-styles

**Problem:**

Interested to know if there are any real-world examples in HTML/CSS when you need to use `display: block` on inline elements. For the reverse order, I found that `display: inline` could be used on `<li>` in a `<nav>` to display links vertically. I am not interested to know the difference between inline, block, and inline-block.

**Current examples:**

Current examples include showing how to use the `display: block` on `<span>` elements, and so forth. But many of these examples only illustrate the *effect* of `display: block` but not the actual use of it on a website.

**Question:**

For what reason and where on a website could it be relevant to use `display: block` to change elements from inline-level to block-level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you wanted to show a big button that links to a site. You use an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (`<a>`) tag because it can contain a hyperlink.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This button's on the same line! <a class="button" href="https://example.com">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

You add your button, but you've run into a problem: The button's on the same row as all the other text. It's [*`inline`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)!

Adding `display: block` not only adds a newline, it also gives you more control about the width and height of the button.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  display: block;

  background: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This button's aligned properly. <a class="button" href="https://example.com">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

> If you wanted to control the button's width and height, while keeping it on the same line, you would use [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow)

Comment: Interesting example, but wouldn't I just need to add a `<p>` element around all content and move the button outside the `<p>` instead of using `display: block`?

Comment: Correct. `display: block` is for situations where you want to keep the content in sections, without wrapping the text in much elements. (Usually for screen readers)